# Error after successfully (?) restarting gnome shell

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have been having a lot of issues with gnome shell extensions lately, I kept seeing an "error" next to the window list extension. I managed to fix this one by simply reinstalling the extensions from the package repository.

Then, I restarted the gnome shell from the terminal (Alt + F2 and r), while everything appears as it should, I get a pop up error, from which a crash file was generated. I found the id in whoopsie as: ***74942958451b6692f0946c3c1f42157e26123b7f841f91801c6c3ddab6cf149580a2865ac9be55ee9f88c2630320be0a889b8ba12f7ccae70b9d006f2902b9dc***

At the same time, the terminal UI appears to be broken, the minimizing button is covered with the small terminal icon: screenshot of my terminal buttons:
[image: screenshot of my terminal buttons]

I am currently running Gnome shell 3.28.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.03. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, so any help would be much appreciated!

Here's the output from running `ls -al /var/crash`

```
-rw-r-----  1 aysun    whoopsie 52511582 Sep  4 20:55 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 aysun    whoopsie        0 Sep  4 20:55 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Sep  4 20:57 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
```

and the list of my extensions (ran `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`)

```
total 44
drwxrwxr-x 11 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 20:47 .
drwx------  3 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  5 13:17 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 12:33 appmenu-regular-icons@example.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 09:37 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 10:19 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 09:12 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 09:24 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 10:32 GmailMessageTray@shuming0207.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 09:10 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 09:39 nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr
drwxrwxr-x  4 aysun aysun 4096 Sep  4 20:47 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

While my Anaconda installation does cause conflict with the `gsettings` command, it isn't related to the bug in gnome-terminal appmenu icon. After some more Googling, I have figured out that this is simply a scaling issue caused by 4K monitors (I'm using a Dell XPS 13 with 4K monitor). I have encountered several problems due to some apps/icons not being DPI aware, so this is just one of them... See [this issue](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme/issues/453), some people suggest downloading gnome-icon-theme, haven't tried that one I simply disabled the appmenu from the titlebar, but I'll leave it here anyways if anyone else is having similar problems.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. You more than likely have a theme problem, or a GNOME extension problem. Temporarily disable ALL GNOME extensions and see if your problems go away.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited my question with the outputs of the two commands. I have just noticed that I have "window-list" extension in both the ~/local folder and the extension folder under root folder. Must have been created when I tried to reinstall this extension to get rid of the "error" on the extension web page. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Delete the `window-list` GNOME extension from both your account, and the root account... it's broken. So if I understand your edit 2, after disabling all extensions, it all worked except the terminal glitch, correct? Now use `GNOME Tweaks` and reset the theme/icons/etc to adwaita, and see if the terminal glitch is gone.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the terminal still looks broken. I thought the window-list was one of the default extensions, that got automatically installed? When I googled I found out several people had problems getting rid of it. Btw, have you seen my third edit, apparently gsettings has a conflict with anaconda libraries as well. I was wondering if you have came across that before @heynnema

Comment: Did switching your theme and icons to Adwaita fix the terminal? Window-List is not one of the default installed extensions. You can safely delete it using the extensions web page at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, or GNOME Tweaks. If you follow the link you gave earlier, you'll lose many of your prefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

- we **deleted** the old `_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.*` files in `/var/crash` to eliminate bogus crash reporting
- we **uninstalled** the `window-list` GNOME extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/,  as it was errored out and caused problems
- we **changed** to the standard adwaita theme and icons to fix a `terminal`-related problem
- we're **testing** GNOME extensions one-at-a-time to see if we can eliminate other problem areas

Comment: I've 1) deleted window-list extension from both local and root accounts, 2) disabled all shell extensions and finally 3) switched back to Adawaita for both themes and icons and rebooted my system, now my terminal UI is fixed. I will try enabling extensions one by one and see if I can isolate it down to the themes.

Comment: @aysun Great news! Let me know how the GNOME extension testing goes.

Comment: Of course I forgot, sorry my mistake! Thank you so much for all the help! I have tested my extensions, and the problem is with the icons. Anything other than the default Adwaita icons breaks the terminal UI... But this is definitely related to the library conflict that I linked to (the one with Anaconda) since when I tried to run any type of `gsettings [command]` I would get the `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.` error and I have the anaconda folder in my path. @heynnema

Comment: @aysun if you remove the anaconda folder from your path, does gsettings work without error? How/where did you add it to your path? Make sure that when your're testing different themes/icons, that you have GNOME extensions disabled, as they can cause similar problems.

Comment: I tried enabling each extension one by one using the default icons, restarting. Buttons broke when I changed the icons, regardless of the theme I was using. The anaconda folder is added to the path in the .bashrc file, so when I run `which gsettings` I get the path to the script in the anaconda folder.

Comment: @aysun It sounds like you're on the right path. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

The giant terminal icon, blocking the small buttons, is filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1770507. Please nag Ubuntu developers to get it fixed. Also see the other bugs linked from there for various possible workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll be following it! Until this bug is taken care of, I've installed `gnome-icon-theme` as a workaround